# Incrementing self variable with decorator function

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I want to increment an id counter for generating jsonrpc calls. I initially wanted to do this with a decorator function which can be annotated the requests methods I will write in the future.

To code:

```py
def increment_id(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # increment id of ServiceInterface.current_id
        args[0].current_id += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class ServiceInterface:
    def __init__(
            self, base_url,
    ):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
        self.current_id = 0
    

    def send(self, payload):
        """
        Returns json dict of JSONPRC request.
        
        Parameters:
            payload (JSONRPC dict): A dictionary in the form of a JSONRPC request.
        
        Returns:
            JSON dictionary response.
        
        """
        response = requests.request(
            "POST", self.base_url, data=payload, headers=self.headers
        )

        if response.ok:
            return response.json()
        else:
            return {"error": {"code": response.status_code, "message": "HTTP Response Error"}}
    
    @increment_id
    def create_payload(self, method, params):
        """
        Creates a JSONRPC request.
        
        Parameters:
            method (str): The RPC method to call. 
            params (dict): The arguments to the method call.
        """
        payload = {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": method,
            "id": self.current_id,
            "params": params,
        }
        return json.dumps(payload)
```

From testing my code it seems like I can't access the variable `current_id` from `args[0]`.

`AttributeError: 'ServiceInterface' object has no attribute 'client_id'`

Code for testing:

```py
import unittest
URL = "http://seed-1.testnet.networks.dash.org:3000/"
# Valid method and parameters for said endpoint
METHOD = "getBlockHash"
PARAMS = {"height": 1}

class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.interface = ServiceInterface(base_url=URL)
    def test_create_payload(self):
        VALID_RPC_PAYLOAD = json.dumps({
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "getBlockHash",
            "id": 1,
            "params": {"height": 1},
        })

        payload = self.interface.create_payload(METHOD, PARAMS)

        # assert correct creation
        self.assertEqual(payload, VALID_RPC_PAYLOAD)

        # assert incrementation of id
        payload_1 = json.loads(self.interface.create_payload(METHOD, PARAMS))
        self.assertEqual(payload_1["id"], 2)
```

The foremost question is how do I access the self variable of the decorated item?
Secondly, is there a more elegant method of achieving this?

Comment: You have a typo somewhere (either in code or in your question). In the code, you trying to access `current_id`, but the error states "`'client_id'` is missing". Please provide the whole traceback

Comment: On the "more elegant", I'd write the wrapper function as taking `self: ServiceInterface, *args, **kwargs` parameters to make it more clear that it's expecting to wrap a `ServiceInterface` method, and allow you to refer to the `ServiceInterface` object as `self` rather than `args[0]`.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Yes! It was just a typo!

Comment: @Samwise That would be more elegant indeed, however, I get `NameError: name 'ServiceInterface' is not defined` when trying to add the parameter. Could you provide a code example? That way I could also accept an answer to the question.

Comment: you can omit the type annotation, or put it in quotes to forward-declare it: `self: 'ServiceInterface', *args, **kwargs`